# Multiline Integer Input in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

```
n = int(input())
numArray = map(int, input().split('\n'))
for i in numArray:
  j=0
  print('Value at x[%d]= %d'%(j,i))
  j+=1
```

I am trying to take multiline integer inputs, but can't seem to get the data after the first line.Is there a way to split the input at new line?

Edited:
Sample Input:

3 //no of inputs
5
4
3

Sample Output:

Value at x[0]=5
Value at x[1]=4
Value at x[2]=3

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to take as input?

Comment: Show a sample input

Comment: integer
3
4
5
1

Comment: all in different lines

Comment: @AshishKumar trying take input in different lines?? or printing input in different lines?

Comment: all of the inputs are in a newline

Comment: Modify your question to clearly show: what's a sample input, and what's your expected output. E.g. input is: 0 1 2 3, output is xxx. Do it in your question to make your question as a minimal workable question.

Comment: @AshishKumar edited the answer.I hope it works for you now!

Comment: @AshishKumar if the solution answers your problem then atleast upvote it and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job

```
def multiple_input():
    try:
        while True:
            data=input()
            if not data: break
            yield data
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

if __name__=='__main__':
    u=list(multiple_input())
    print(u)
    for i in u:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iter() method.

Code -

```
sentinel = ''
multi_line = ','.join(iter(input,sentinel))
list = multi_line.split(',')
```